# The De Morgan Formulas (for finite sets )

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Pick an arbitrarily but fixed $w\in\Omega\;$ where $\mathbb{N}_n^* = \{1,2,...,n\}$. Then

$$
\begin{align}
w\in\left(\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}_n^*} A_k \right)^C &\Longrightarrow w \notin \left(\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}_n^*} A_k \right)\\
&\Longrightarrow \neg \left[w \in \left(\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}_n^*} A_k \right) \right]\\
&\Longrightarrow \neg \{w\in\Omega:\exists k\in\mathbb{N}_n^*\; s.t.\; w\in A_k \}\\
&\Longrightarrow \{w\in\Omega:\forall k\in\mathbb{N}_n^*;s.t.\;w\notin A_k\}\\
&\Longrightarrow w\in\left(\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{N}_n^*} A_k^C\right)\\
\end{align}
$$

Similarly, with regards to *de Morgans 2nd Law*:

$$
\begin{align}
w\in\left(\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{N}_n^*} A_k \right)^C &\Longrightarrow w \notin \left(\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{N}_n^*} A_k \right)\\
&\Longrightarrow \neg \left[w \in \left(\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{N}_n^*} A_k \right) \right]\\
&\Longrightarrow \neg \{w\in\Omega:\forall k\in\mathbb{N}_n^*\; s.t.\; w\in A_k \}\\
&\Longrightarrow \{w\in\Omega:\exists k\in\mathbb{N}_n^*\; s.t.\; w\notin A_k \}\\
&\Longrightarrow w\in\left(\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}_n^*} A_k^C\right)\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Notice the implications are equivalances and that the same proof will work for infinite collections of sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have shown is that if $w \in \left(\cup_k A_k\right)^c$ then $w \in \cap_k A_k^c$, that is $\left(\cup_k A_k\right)^c \subset \cap_k A_k^c$. You must also show the reverse inclusion. In fact, all your implications ($\implies$) are equivalences $(\iff)$, but I leave you to check that.

Other than that your proofs are fine. You may observe that you never explicitly use that your index set is the 'finite naturals', so you may exchange it for any arbitrary index set (hence the general De Morgan's).

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but what do you consider an arbitrary index set? The infinite set of natural numbers? Or really just any set?

Comment: @Stefan It means any set, i.e. infinite or not